# mercury rails gem issue with value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, mercury-editor

I am using ercury-rails gem, where you can find it [here](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury) . Everything works well, except the params[:value]. I am keep getting "br tag" at the end of my text, that I want to update. So my parameter looks like this

```
Parameters: {"content"=>{"post_title"=>{"type"=>"full", "value"=>"yeah<br>"}
```

Anyone maybe has an idea, why that happens? Btw here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('mercury:ready', function () {
        var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
        Mercury.saveUrl = "<%= mercury_update_admin_post_path(@post) %>";
        link.hide();
    });


</script>
<div id="container">
    <div><p id="notice"><%= notice %></p></div>

    <div>
        <h2><span id="post_title" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable" data-mercury="full"><%= @post.title %></span></h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <%= @post.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")%>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post-body">
        <div id="post_body" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable" data-mercury="full">
            <%= raw simple_format(@post.body) %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', "/editor" + request.path, :class => "btn", :id => "edit_link" %>
        <%= link_to 'Back', admin_posts_path, :class => "btn" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks. I would be really glad, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is some documentation to removing the br tag from your content, please go though this.
I hope if you go through this url you might be getting some solutions.

[BR tag issue](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/issues/34)

In the above url you will have the some options to disble the br tag at the end.

```
pageEditor = new Mercury.FormPageEditor('form.mercury-form', options);
pageEditor.document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn', false, false);
```

I hope this helps.